# What does @ mean next to the file attributes in unix?

Tags: unix, file-attributes

I noticed I have one file that looks like this when I type `ls -lah` in the terminal:

```
-rw-r--r--@    1 bj5  1704   2.3M 13 Mar 16:12 All_Metadata.csv
```

I was just curious as to what the `@` symbol means? I presumed it's a file attribute but I googled it and couldn't find any reference to it.

Comment: This belongs *@* http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: ...or at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). From http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic -- a question has to be "unique to software development" to be a fit for SO. (In this case, it probably means that POSIX ACLs exist for the file, but that's going to be something specific to your OS -- it's not a convention true for all Unixen).

Comment: Ben, what is your Unix? Is it linux or BSD or Macos or something else? What is the version of your `ls` utility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're tagged `unix`, the controlling standard that applies to all Unixen is [IEEE 1003.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html). Quoting from same:

> The file mode written under the -l, -n, [XSI] [Option Start] -g, and -o [Option End] options shall consist of the following format:
>
> ```
> "%c%s%s%s%s", <entry type>, <owner permissions>,
>     <group permissions>, <other permissions>,
>     <optional alternate access method flag>
> ```
>
> The `<optional alternate access method flag>` shall be the empty string if there is no alternate or additional access control method associated with the file; otherwise, it shall be a string containing a single printable character that is not a `<blank>`.

Thus, this tells us that there is "an alternate or additional access control method associated with the file". Typically, this is something like an ACL, which a command like `getfacl` (on a Linux system) may retrieve and view.

---

Specifically for MacOS, however, the documentation `ls` specifies that presence of xattrs is shown with this character. Quoting from its man page:

> If the file or directory has extended attributes, the permissions field printed by the `-l` option is followed by a '@' character.  Otherwise, if the file or directory has extended security information (such as an access control list), the permissions field printed by the `-l` option is followed by a '+' character.

Thus, on MacOS, presence of ACLs is indicated with `@`, and ACLs are represented with `+`.

Comment: What is the option of macos `ls` or other macos command to list full ACL data?

Comment: `ls -le` will print ACLs; `ls -l@` will list xattrs.

Answer (score 0):

The "@" sign indicates that the file has extended attributes. You can use the command 'xattr -l ' to show them. It seems that a lot of Finder information, which ought to be stored in the catalog, is now in extended attributes.

Comment: If xattrs, vs ACLs, are being displayed that way, that's arguably a violation of the relevant POSIX spec for `ls` (which reserves that character for "access control methods").

Comment: Brian, where is this documented?

Comment: ...that said, from the MacOS `ls` man page, it looks like it does indeed behave this way, violation or no.

Comment: Copy of macos `man ls` online: https://ss64.com/osx/ls.html "*If the file or directory has extended attributes, the permissions field printed by the -l option is followed by an @ character. Otherwise, if the file or directory has extended security information, the permissions field printed by the -l option is followed by a + character.*"; duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97241/ http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1646